# Enforce compilation dependencies with Ant compiler tasks

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

There are certain compiler dependencies that are not allowed in our (Java) environment. We have two servers, call them Application and Process. We have three root Java packages, call them Application, Process, and Shared. Application and Process are not allowed to reference each other, but they can each reference Shared. Shared can reference any class in any of the other two packages. How can I enforce these dependencies with Ant? The problem, as you might guess, is that in our Eclipse based environment everything compiles successfully, but we've come across runtime errors where a class is not there (since we have multiple servers).

I have attempted quite a few things but nothing has worked. See my current attempt below, where I have omitted irrelevant code for clarity. Comments are included.

```
<!--Compile the 'shared' directories. Since shared depends on Application and Process, we compile everything then delete Application and Process later. -->
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
        <classpath>
            ...
        </classpath>
      </javac>


<delete dir="${build.dir}/application" />
<delete dir="${build.dir}/process" />

<!--Compile the 'application' directories -->
<javac sourcepath="" srcdir="${src.dir}/application" destdir="${build.dir}">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${build.dir}/shared" /> 
        ...
    </classpath>
  </javac>

<!--Compile the 'process' directories -->
<javac sourcepath="" srcdir="${src.dir}/process" destdir="${build.dir}">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${build.dir}/shared" /> 
            ...
        </classpath>
  </javac>
```

Comment: Isn't having Application and Shared reference each other a circular dependency?

Comment: @cdhowie Yes it is circular, but that's just how our code base is right now. In a perfect world all "shared" code would be in Shared package, but as of now, the only 'rule' is that Application/Process should not reference each other. However, in at least one instance, they do, which causes a run time failure.

Comment: @cdhowie Does that mean you're saying my weird dependency enforcement is impossible, or were you just commenting to say 'Hey, you shouldn't do that'?

Comment: I'm saying that this is going to cause trouble down the road.  If you have Shared referencing App and Process, and both of those referencing Shared, then *App and Process indirectly reference each other anyway.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for a way to prevent to usage of java.sql.Statement in project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882804/looking-for-a-way-to-prevent-to-usage-of-java-sql-statement-in-project)

Comment: @MarkO'Connor How could it be a duplicate, the technologies being used are not the same and the problem description isn't that similar. I'm not using Maven, Owasp, or Sonar... That being said I don't think this question can be answered, so might as well close...

Comment: @KyleM Instead of trying to this during the compilation stage, use Sonar to perform source code analysis. Sonar supports Architectural rules that forbid parts of your code calling other parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to split shared into three parts, shared-standalone, shared-application and shared-process.

compile shared-standalone first,

compile shared-application together with application,

compile shared-process together with process.

Comment: Can't do that.. there are too many dependencies, it would take a while to split it up and then test again. I can't get approval for that. If a class in Shared calls stuff in Process AND Application, then I'd need to create a class in both, so it wouldn't even be a 1-1 split.

Comment: Then you are out of luck, because you have a self-conflicting requirement. Really this is crying out for refactoring, shared should be self contained.